# Delete my Google Account, what will happen when someone sends me a calendar invite via mail?

Tags: email, dropbox, calendar

I have a **G Suite account for the domain mydomain.com**, which includes an email email@mydomain.com and a Calendar associated with that email.

I decided to migrate away from Google, but they don't have any function to convert a G Suite account to a regular one, and so I will lose my Google Calendar access.

How can I keep the calendar working? I pointed my MX records of mydomain.com to an email hosting service, but they don't offer calendar.

If I export my .ics from my current Google Calendar and feed it to a local calendar app, **what will happen when someone sends me an invite via mail**? Will I have to manually added the event to that calendar? I am a bit confused how one's supposed to keep a calendar and link it to their email without using cloud services.

Can I just host the calendar file on Dropbox?

Comment: What "local caledar app" you will be using? Does it includes a web based calendar service? Does it's integrated with your email client?

Answer (score 0):

One option that could consider is the following:

Once your G Suite account is deleted (may should should wait sometime for the change propagate accross the Google data centers) you can create a free Google Account using your "mydomain.com" email address as your primary email address (you will not have access to Gmail) or you could add you "mydomain.com" email address as a secondary email address to your Google account.

People will be able to share a calendar with you and see your busy/free info if you allow them to do that but if you send an invitation the invitation will be sent in behalf of your primary email address.